# Changing domain for Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site which allows users to register by Facebook. Associated Facebook application is assigned to the domain, for example, www.abcd.cl. At present, there are a lot of registered users. Besides that domain, if users connect using other domain, for example, www.efgh.cl, they will be redirected to the main domain www.abcd.cl.

Well... customer needs now that the main domain to be www.efgh.cl and the secondary www.abcd.cl. So, if someone enters in www.abcd.cl, he will be redirected to www.efgh.cl.

The question is, after I change all DNS matters, can I just change the domain in Facebook App? what about current registered users?

I have this question because when the site was under development, we used the URL dev.abcd.cl. I registered with my facebook account at that time. When we passed to production, URL changed to www.abcd.cl. From that time on, I cannot log in using Facebook. I receive the error: "user already registered".

Comment: You can just change url. Why you got that erro before had nothing to do with changing the domain in the app settings.

Comment: That is curious.... the real fact is that after domain change, I could not log in using facebook anymore.

Comment: Then something in your code is probably at fault

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Log into Facebook Developers, then add your new domain to the "App Domains" field under the "Settings" tab.  Also change your "Site URL", your "Secure Canvas URL" on the same page.  Save, and you are fixed up!